# python3 SqlAlchemy error TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy, oursql

I am writing a django app that calls a script using SQLAlchemy. The following query runs successfully with Python v2.x:

```
  engine = create_engine('mysql+oursql://ag:529382Ag@localhost/gp?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0',pool_recycle=3600)    
  query = "select a.gid as entrez, a.source_id as "+id_dict[ids[0]]+", b.source_id as "+id_dict[ids[1]]+" from (select * from gid2source_id where gid2source_id.id_type_id = "+str(ids[0])+") a, (select * from gid2source_id where gid2source_id.id_type_id= "+str(ids[1])+") b where b.gid = a.gid;"    
  result1 = engine.execute(query)
```

When run with Python v3.x, the following error is received:

```
line 105, in get_results result1 = engine.execute(query.decode('utf-8'))
...
line 2453, in initialize self._detect_ansiquotes(connection)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py",
line 2730, in _detect_ansiquotes
self._server_ansiquotes = 'ANSI_QUOTES' in mode TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent versions of SQLAlchemy and whichever MySQL connector is in use.

Comment: @BryanEargle I am using sqlalchemy 0.9.8 and oursql 0.9.4 I believe these are quite up to date

Comment: Try an [alternate connector](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb) to narrow down what's causing the error - there's quite a few to choose from. This looks like a bug in either SQLAlchemy or the MySQL connector, my uneducated guess is the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess oursql doesn't interface properly in python3. I switched to mysqlconnector and it works fine.